# Multiple meanings of 授業に出る

Tags: word-usage

I noticed that instead of 授業に行く, my textbook uses 授業に出る. Furthermore, when I checked the dictionary, I found three quite different meanings for 授業に出る:

- (e.g., a student) go to class
- (e.g., a professor) teach a class
- (e.g., a topic) come up in a class

Questions:

1. How are these three meanings tied to the same verb 出る?
2. Is there any nuance difference between 行くand 出る in the first meaning?

(If any of the three meanings are not commonly used in spoken Japanese, please point it out.)

Comment: The meaning of 授業に出る is very broad (I understand this is exactly the point at issue), so it would help if you could you add *more context* to your sentences. I.e. could you add the *full* sentence (or better yet, the whole paragraph) from your textbook where 授業に出る is used? It is just a little extra effort from your side that goes a long way to find a successful and meaningful answer.

Comment: The example I saw in the textbook was: 今日は授業に出る他は、何も予定がない。I guess it fits well with your explanation, something like "Today, besides showing up in class, I have no plans"

Comment: 出る meaning "to appear (in public)" is used with various words. 会議に出る (to attend a meeting), 映画に出る (to perform/appear in a movie), 人前に出る (to stand/appear in front of people), 選挙に出る (to run for election), 試験に出る (to be asked in an exam), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between 行くand 出る in all of the three cases that you posted is the following:

行く means that there is an actual movement, i.e. someones moves **from** whatever place **to** the classroom:

> [会社から]日本語の授業に行きました。

In the case of 出る, whatever the meaning you pick up, there is **no movement**. All the action happens *only* in the classroom:

1. (e.g., a student) to **attend** a class (I think that to "go" to a
   class is a misleading translation)
2. (e.g., a professor) to teach a class
3. (e.g., a    topic) to come up in a class

Some example sentences for each use:

1. 歴史の授業に出る。 To attend a history lesson.
2. 田中先生は病気なので、今日の授業に出られない。Professor Tanaka is sick, so he will not teach today's lesson.
3. この問題は昨日の授業に出た。This problem came up in yesterday's class.

---

Finally, to answer your questions, first:

> Is there any nuance difference between 行くand 出る in the first meaning?

It feels somewhat wrong to use 授業に行くto mean "to take a lesson", because the emphasis is in the action of moving towards the class, rather than the act of taking the lesson, so I would say they have different meanings altogether. Also note that for the action of attending lessons in a regular fashion or under some kind of schedule, there is the verb 通{かよ}う:

> 毎週フランス語の授業に通っている。 I attend French lessons every week.

As for the second question:

> How are these three meanings tied to the same verb 出る?

The point in common between all of this usages of 出る is that, rather than "going", someone or something (the student, the teacher or the problem) "appears" in the lesson. In the meaning 1, that would mean "showing up" as a student in a particular class.

---

As I commented in the original question, if you add the full sentence from your textbook where 授業に出る is used we might be able to help you further.